# Firebase google-services.json file

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have a question regarding the Firebase google-services.json file. Every time I add o change something, for example, if I add a new SHA1 fingerprint, do I need to download the file again and put it on the app folder of my Android project? or just the file created the first time is enough?

I am asking because I am having issues with the Phone authentication and I need to know if the problem lies on this matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, every time you add a fingerprint (or new package name) you will need to pull down the `google-services.json`.

Comment: As a side note, after you add the SHA1 signature in the Firebase configuration, it is also added into the .json file, so you have to add it back to the project. If you have multiple flavors or projects, just create all of them at once. (debug, release, staging, etc)

Comment: Thank you, and would you mind to explain me why does the phone authentication work only sometimes. I mean, is it normal the need to wait for hours to make it work sometimes?. I haven´t change the code and for hours I don´t receive any SMS with the verification code,and suddenly  I try again and it works again.

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain why that would happen. Though I have seen SMS messages take hours to arrive (not just verification codes from firebase.)

Comment: I have a problem, after I added new fingerprint and pull down the google-services.json, the file is not changed and no new certificate_fingerprint is added.. I have had no luck for days...