# Adding SSH-1 from firebase doesn't update google-services.json file

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, ssh-keys

Hello I am facing issue that my `google-services.json` file is not updating after adding new fingerprint from Firebase console. I have generated debug SSH-1 from terminal and added that SSH-1 to firebase console but after downloading new `google-services.json` I found my new `oauth_client` array is not updating with new certificate. Please help me this

```
   "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "508076951118-vg2ihk02grdoje0t0fmfdkimtn3a7kqs.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.money.demo",
        "certificate_hash": "My Machine Hash"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "XXXXX06951118-1of05gfhorr28fvp3jp821sihf6j4lqn.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
```

Even after adding two SSH-1 in firebase console. I see no changes to it

Comment: Did you ever solve this without re-adding the hashes. Because that doesn't work and I don't want to do it again for 14 apps just to check

Answer (score -1):

google-services.json is not related to SSH-1 fingerprint either the debug or the release

Comment: Can you please check this anwer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351579/firebase-google-services-json-file

Comment: as far as I know If you changed the package name (not change the SHH-1) you need to red download the file

Comment: No I guess for both things we need to re download google-services.json as google-services.json contains all SSH-1 added in Firebase console. For my current project I can see all 6 previously added SSH1 added in google-services.json and same SSH1 in Firebase console.

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue. I've added 2 SHA1 fingerprints but neither does google-services.json reflect it, nor does my firebase authentication work. Did you find a way out?

Comment: @KKM Yes I am following up with Firebase support team. I will update if any explanation comes up from their end.

Comment: This is what some Firebase support member has told me 
"We found some issues with the oAuth clients in Firebase and the GCP console, basically we are not seeing reflected the oAuth clients in the google-services.json file after this ones are added, we are still investigating why this is happening, but in the meantime a workaround will be delete the SHA-1  and SHA-256 that you have and add it again, download the updated file then clean and rebuild."
I tried it, but it didn't reflect any change in my google-services.json file.

Answer (score -1):

I have struggled with this problem as well. What you need to do is first delete **EVERY SHA-1 AND SHA-256** fingerprint from Firebase console (refresh and download the `google-services.json` file just in case after doing this step), then add the fingerprints again, refresh the page and download the `google-services.json` file one more time. I tested this workaround today and it worked.